# How can I get my Sphinx body content to load when I apply customisation to my theme?

Tags: jinja2, themes, python-sphinx

I need to amend certain elements on my Sphinx project. A `h1` here and `button` there, I can get the custom elements I want but it seems to negate the content rendering. Screenshots at the end of this post.

What I do:

1. I copy these files below:

```
versions.html
theme.conf
breadcrumbs.html
footer.html
layout.html
search.html
searchbox.html
```

From:`...Sphinx-Project/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sphinx_rtd_theme`

To: `/Users/moeh/repos/DeveloperDoc/Cameron/Web/_templates` This is the directory where markup is customised.

1. Create a `page.html` file in the `_templates` directory with the following code in place.

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{{ super() }}
```

I've tried variations of this code snippet, most sources show this as the typical way to customise themes.

All the customisations are in there as intended but the main body content doesn't render.
The body copy renders as expected if the `templates_path = ['_templates']` is omitted in the `conf.py` file but then the custom elements don't take.

If you're wondering, the custom markup I include is in the `searchbox.html` at the moment. I tested it and just including the customise template without any markup edits negates the body content rendering.

Without `_templates` reference:
[image]

With `_templates` reference:
[image]

Screencap of my folder structure:
[image]